# Another factorial option for c

Tags: c, algorithm, function, factorial

I just got to do this:

Write a repetition program that will calculate the following statements (n<10)and show the calculation result 1+1/2!+1/3!.......+1/n!

I know that is a factorial what i have to do, but is inverted (^-1) and have a condition, **do I have to include float or something of that?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getValue()
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &n);

    return(n);
}

int factorial(int n)
{
    int i, f;

    f = 1;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    f = f * i;

    return(f);
}

void printFactorial(int f)
{
    printf("The factorial is: %d", f);
}

int main()
{
    int f = getValue();

    factorial(f);
    printFactorial();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Your `scanf` call expects more arguments than it's getting.

Comment: Ask yourself how _you_ would calculate the formula. By term. And wouldn't you at 1/4! calculate 4! using the prior result of 3! of 1/3!? Use `double` as floating point datatype.

Comment: @chris OP's `scanf()` call is OK.  Review the meaning of `*` in `scanf()`.

Comment: @chux, It turns out I just suck. I can't even find what I remember in relation to that.

Answer (score 3):

For f=1+1/2!+1/3!.......+1/n!

No need to use factorial

How about this ?

```
    double term=1.0;
    double f=1.0;

    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
     term*=1.0/i;
     f+=term;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well I explored some options, namely,

The simple way:

```
double sum = 1;
double fact = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    fact *= i;
    sum += 1 / fact;
}
```

The Kahan Sum:

```
double sum = 1;
double fact = 1;
double correction = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    fact *= i;
    double y = (1 / fact) - correction;
    double t = sum + y;
    correction = (t - sum) - y;
    sum = t;
}
```

The Rational Sum:

```
double numerator = 1;
double denominator = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    numerator = numerator * i + 1;
    denominator = denominator * i;
}
double result = numerator / denominator;
```

The simple way and Kahan Sum gave the same result. Apparently the factorial drives that reciprocal down so quickly that there's just nothing left to sum to anything of any consequence after `n = 16`.

The rational sum gave a *slightly* different answer (slightly less accurate), but was a bit faster in my test.

Comment: +1 for impresive answer and interesint recherge (but maybe here a bit too much, as just n=10 is needed, but it may help others)

Comment: noo why trouble :( / #include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
double sum = 1;
double fact = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++);
{
fact *= i;
sum += 1 / fact;
return(f);
void printFactorial(int f)
{
printf("The factorial is: %d", f);
int main()
{
int f = getValue();
factorial(f);
printFactorial();
return(0);
getch();
return 0;
}

Comment: @JAce you're returning out of the loop, that's probably bad

Answer (score 1):

You got mostly correctly. And declare the type of `f` to be double.

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++) // Outer loop to make `n` number of summations
{
    for ( ... )     // Inner loop to calculate factorial of denominators
    {
       // factorial logic here
    }
    f = f + (double) (1/factorial result);
}
```

Hope you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate sum_(i=1)^(n) (1/(i!)) right?

I would do one for-loop to sum up all the rationals (which need to be doubles). And one for-loop for each to calculate a denominator and do the division 1/denominator afterwards.

like that:

```
f=0;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    denominator = 1; // sorry initialized first time with zero...
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++) denominator *= j;
    f+= 1/(double)denominator;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `denominator *= j`? Also, you don't have to calculate the denominator from scratch each time, you can simply multiply the previous one by `i`.

Comment: @Omri... 1) wow ok, true. 2) Yeah if I rethink it, that's true, but there is always a better solution ;)

Comment: still give me back too many errors,could u help me to rebuild it i think i'm typing it wrong

Comment: `printf' undeclared (first use this function),  (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.) 24  too few arguments to function `void printFactorial(int)'

Comment: why do you write in your scanf-routine "%d%*c" ? is "%d" notenough or am I just not familiar with this syntax?

Comment: probably is my mistake

Comment: you also don't give an Argument to printFactorial() and you dont catch the return value of factorial(int n) in main and f should be a double in main, so maybe take n from getValue() and get f from factorial(n)

Comment: you also need to change the variable in printFactorial(int f) to double f, as f is better a double than an integer, after that and declaring denominator in factorial it should compile

Comment: After compiling I found one tricky more... printf("%d") gives you a decimal for double you will need %lf, also denominator needs to be initialized by 1, (watch out not to do so with 0 ;)

Comment: And now it should return just decimals. For the last error, watch out that return variable types fit the return variable you want to store them in ;)

Answer (score 0):

You almost had the factorial part.  Just needed to do

```
printFactorial(factorial(f));
```

But to get to the "f=1+1/2!+1/3!.......+1/n!", recommend a **recursive solution**.  You get *better* numeric results if you sum the smallest factional terms first.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

double JAceHelper(double Factorial, int i, int n) {
  if (i >= n) {
    return 0.0;
    }
  i++;
  return 1/Factorial + JAceHelper(Factorial * i, i, n);
}

// For f=1+1/2!+1/3!.......+1/n!
double JAce(int n) {
  if (n < 0) return 1.0;  // error
  if (n < 1) return 1.0;
  return JAceHelper(1.0, 1, n);
}

int main() {
  int n;
  printf("Enter number: ");
  scanf("%d%*c", &n);
  printf("Sum is %20.15lf\n", JAce(n));
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: But isn't it always better to go for a for-loop then do a recursion (if possible), because of better runtime?

Comment: @Martin Better runtime is a worthy goal, and a loop usually has better speed than recursion.  It is O(n) that one should watch out for, followed by maintenance before minor speed issues.  BTW: There is a way to do the reverse add without recursion - thought a recursive solution look fun.

Comment: I did not want to blame your solution. It is always good to see other possibilities. I just wanted to point that out, for them who would not have thought about it and to know, what you think about. Thanks for replying ;)

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* solutions use floating point.

If you want to **improve you accuracy**, one should sum the smallest terms together first.   I posted a recursive solution elsewhere to do this, but a **simple** non-recursive solution follows and is compared to another popular answer.

The 2 methods (using float) were compared to the same methods using double (not shown) to determine the relative errors.  The "sum smallest terms first" was never beaten by "sum largest terms first".

Note:
1+1/2!+1/3!.......+1/n! = (( (((1/n + 1)/(n-1) + 1)/(n-2) + 1) ... )/2 + 1/1

```
float f1(int n) {  // sum smallest terms together first
  float sum = 0.0;
  while (n >= 1) {
    sum = (1.0f + sum) / n;
    n--;
  }
  return sum;
}

float f2(int n) { // sum largest terms together first
  float term = 1.0;
  float f = 1.0;
  int i;
  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    term *= 1.0f / i;
    f += term;
  }
  return f;
}

void ftest(int n) {
  double y = (d1(n) + d2(n))/2;  // d1,d2 is a double version of f1,f2 (not shown)
  printf("f1 %2d %.8e %+e\n", n, f1(n), (f1(n) - y)/y);
  printf("f2 %2d %.8e %+e\n", n, f2(n), (f2(n) - y)/y);
}

int main() {
  int i;
  for (i = 5; i < 9; i++)
    ftest(i);
  return 0;
}

f1  5 1.71666670e+00 +1.851795e-08  // The exact answer is 1.716666...
f2  5 1.71666658e+00 -5.092436e-08
f1  6 1.71805549e+00 -4.008979e-08
f2  6 1.71805549e+00 -4.008979e-08
f1  7 1.71825397e+00 +1.101240e-09
f2  7 1.71825385e+00 -6.827691e-08
f1  8 1.71827877e+00 -2.422694e-09
f2  8 1.71827865e+00 -7.179985e-08
```

Comment: Why `float` anywhere instead of `double`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 3 approaches are compared: sum small to largest, sum largest to small and a reference function `(d1(n) + d2(n))/2`. The ref function is done in a higher precision `double` (presumably being far more correct regardless of approach taken) and the other 2 in a lower one `float`. Thus one can compare if summing "up" or summing "down" is better.    "sum smallest terms first" was marginally better -thus demonstrating an example that "one should sum the smallest terms together first"